# confused with xpath

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I've got this PHP code loading in some html.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($somehtml);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$divContent = $xpath->query('//table[class="defURLP"]');

echo $divContent;
```

I'm too confused to understand quite what needs to go on here, however my desire would it to be able to populate the variable $divContent to have the html contents of the table with the classname defURLP

It's currently just returning

```
object(DOMNodeList)#3 (0) { }
```

Comment: What does your XML look like ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to retrieve the first item from the DOMNodeList returned by your xpath query, since there may be more than one in the list.

```
// Queries for tables having class defURLP
$tables = $xpath->query('//table[class="defURLP"]');
// Reference the first one in $divContent
$divContent = $tables->item(0);
// Output its nodeValue
echo $divContent->nodeValue;
```

Or iterate over the node list with a `foreach`:

```
$tables = $xpath->query('//table[class="defURLP"]');
// Iterate over the whole node list in $tables (if it is multiple nodes)
foreach ($tables as $t) {
  echo $t->nodeValue;
}
```